# Who should the beta moderators be?

Tags: discussion

> If your meta site does not have a post to nominate Moderators, start one now! Pro Tem appointments will begin about two weeks after the site is created. The more guidance we receive, the more informed our choice. [Moderator Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)

- **Each nomination should be a separate answer**. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity.
- The nominee should indicate their acceptance by editing the answer, adding that they accept the nomination. Optionally they can write something about themselves.
- **Self nominations are okay, and even encouraged**. Most sites have not had sufficient time for many users to stand out. Self nomination is simply a way to say, “I’m interested. Let my record speak for itself.” Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, blog posts reviewing or announcing the site, etc.

We're looking for members of movies.stackexchange.com who:

- Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

It's also good if the moderators:

- Are members with participation in both meta.movies.stackexchange.com and movies.stackexchange.com.
- Participated in Area 51, generate social network referrals, or blog about the site.
- Are members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.

*After the site graduates from beta, elections will be held to choose moderators. For the beta period, Stack Exchange staff will decide who the moderators are, but it's best if volunteers put themselves forward and receive a favorable community response.*

Comment: I do suggest that (contrary to how this is normally done outside of SE) that people who are interested nominate themselves freely - I can think of a dozen people who could contribute as moderators - including @flimzy and mnementh

Answer (score 8):

## [iandotkelly](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/40)

[image: iandotkelly]

[image: iandotkelly]

Following the guidelines above, I accept the nomination.  I am not prone to pushing myself forward but I (think) I would both enjoy and learn from being a moderator - and would try my best to do a good job if selected.

I was not a big contributor to the original Area51 discussions about the site, mostly because I only started getting involved in Stackexchange fairly recently - joining SO in July when my job changed to a more technical one again.

However since the Beta launched I have found myself enjoying contributing to the site and the discussion about how it should evolve.  You will see from my record, that I am personally more interested in helping to research and answer questions than pose them myself, and that is always going to me my primary contribution here, but I have also been involved in non Q&A activities, such as editing a lot of tags to build the site as a resource.  I have seen the moderators work here and on other SE sites, and it is sometimes a difficult line to walk between being welcoming and keeping things on-topic.  I realize that being moderator does not mean that you set the areas that are on or off-topic, that is for the community - so I would continue to participate in the meta discussions about the direction here.

I am based in the USA but I am originally from the UK so I have some understanding that although this is an English language site, it has users all over the world.

Answer (score 8):

I'll throw my hat in the ring

[image: A DForck42]

[image: A DForck42]

I'm a pro tem mod on literature.stackexchange.com, and I love movies as well as books.

Answer (score 5):

### Shads0

[image: profile for Shads0 at Movies, Q&A for film aficionados]

[image: profile for Shads0 at Movies Meta, Q&A about the site for film aficionados]

---

I'll throw my hat in the ring if for nothing else to say I tried.

I love movies and have always been interested in the trivia of movies and little quirks that can intrigue me.  I may not consider myself the De facto movie buff but I do know more than the average person and am always willing to research for an answer or offer my thoughts if a concrete answer does not exist/is hard to find.

As far as SE experience goes, I am relatively new to the network of sites, joining SF in  late July and while I have not gotten a high rep, I have a very high FW (currently 653) so I do know how to weed useful items from not and I am not wholly  new to the concept of being a moderator or a type of representative for a collective or being in any type of position of power.

Comment: Its strange that you got less up-votes.

Answer (score 3):

## Alonzo

[image: Alonzo]

[image: Alonzo]

<s>I'm interested in helping out temporarily. I really think that this site has a lot of potential to be a great site. But first we need a solid scope.</s>

I revoke my decision got some things to handle. Sorry about that.